# Commerce 2 order receipt email – how to hide and then output later the shipping method in the twig email template?

Tags: commerce

We have a custom TWIG email receipt template that is outputting the shipping method from the shipping_information variable.

The TWIG template is using the default code to output the shipping information:

```
{% if shipping_information %}
 <td>
     {% block shipping_information %}
      {{ shipping_information }}
     {% endblock %}
 </td>
{% endif %}
```

The code above outputs the shipping method along with the shipping_information variable. We'd like to not output the shipping method here and instead output it later in the template.

Comment: it would help to post the actual contents of the file as no one can say with custom stuff.

Comment: Added the code as requested.